# why is every second "if input.axis" statement is failing without error when trying to detect a RayCastHit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls, raycasting

I am creating a 3D top-down game and I am wanting to make a character move around though i am using ray casts to make sure that when the characters collides it does continue to change it's position when the character is trying to move against it.

I have create code such as:

```
[SerializeField] private float speed = 5;


    public float XMovement;
    public float ZMovement;
    public Vector3 RotationY;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        MovementSetting();
        

        var dir = new Vector3(XMovement, 0, ZMovement);
        transform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    
    void MovementSetting()
    {
        var ray = new Ray();
        RaycastHit hit;

        // If input is "a"
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            RotationY = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left);
            ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, RotationY);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 0.6f)) { XMovement = 0; }
            else { XMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); }
        }
        else { XMovement = 0; }

        // If input is "d"
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            RotationY = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
            ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, RotationY);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 0.6f)) { XMovement = 0; }
            else { XMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); }
        }
        else { XMovement = 0; }

        // If input is "s"
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
        {
            RotationY = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.back);
            ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, RotationY);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 0.6f)) { ZMovement = 0; }
            else { ZMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); }
        }
        else { ZMovement = 0; }

        // If input is "w"
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
        {
            RotationY = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, RotationY);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 0.6f)) { ZMovement = 0; }
            else { ZMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); }
        }
        else { ZMovement = 0; }

        
    }
```

in theory this is meant to work though, only every second "if input" statement 100% works

I find that as soon as it reaches `if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 0.6f))` for every odd "if input", it stops working, though doesn't throw an error code

I tried using debug.log to see if there was any response in the "if physics" respone which I didn't get.

I also tried (dumb idea) seeing if I double the "if input" statements twice, therefore every second one should work, that didn't work either

Comment: you are using else conditions and then creating a conditional asking for the case that is already entering in the else, this is making you get the impression that "odd" things works, just remove your "else's" and put it inside a condition to check if the value is 0

Comment: are there ways to tick a comment as a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not failing. But the second if-statement may revert the `XMovement` the first one sets:

```cs
// Let's assume the horizontal axis is < 0 ...
if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) {
    XMovement = ...; // ... then a value will be assigend here.
} else {
    XMovement = 0;
}

if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) {
    // We said it's < 0, so this code will not be executed
} else {
    XMovement = 0; // however, this one will
                   // and thus the value we assigned earlier will be cleared!
}
```

Let's re-organize the code

```cs
float horizontalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
if (horizontalAxis < 0) {
    XMovement = ...;
} else if (horizontalAxis > 0) {
    XMovement = ...;
} else { // horizontalAxis == 0
    XMovement = 0;
}
```

Now, always exactly one branch will ever be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using else conditions and then creating a conditional asking for the case that is already entering in the else, this is making you get the impression that "odd" things work, just remove your "else's" and put it inside a condition to check if the value is 0